# Do you have to store resource if you publish it via rest api?

Tags: rest, design-patterns

Let's say I have a rest api with a following endpoint: `/foos/{fooId}` which returns some object named of type foo. Now let's say I store different kind of resource in my database underneath, which is bars. Sample bar has some barId, and my resource available via api (foo) is a projection of a bar plus some other stuff. Does this design makes sense? If I don't store resource named foo and there is no such thing as fooId (just a projection of bar), is my api still restful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An API is RESTful if it follows the design principles of REST, particularly if it's a [level 3](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) API.

It's the view as seen by a client that matters. How state is stored is an implementation detail that has no direct impact on whether or not a HTTP API is RESTful. The client doesn't see your database.

You could envision a REST API that has *no* underlying data store; one that gives you the date and time of day, for example. It'd still be RESTful as long as it plays by the REST rules.

Good resources to learn about RESTful design are the [RESTful Web Services Cookbook](https://amzn.to/37ORT2X) and [REST in Practice](https://amzn.to/3sti0Eu).

Comment: +1 -- there are reasons for storing a resource directly, and reasons for *not* doing so -- for example to return a resource (transformed) in the context of the client's request.

Answer (score 1):

> If I don't store resource named foo and there is no such thing as fooId (just a projection of bar), is my api still restful?

There is nothing in REST or HTTP that constrains your storage implementation.

If producing a representation of your resource requires seven databases, two clocks, a external camera and a hot cup of Earl Gray tea, that's *fine*.  The "rules", such as they are, are all about what the messages *mean*, not how you produce them.

You are allowed to use any spelling convention you want for your resource identifiers.  People will usually choose a design that makes things easier for some people (for example, the operators looking at the URI in the HTTP access logs).

If your resource identifier is going to be [long lived](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI) (and in particular, if it is going to outlive any specific implementation), then you probably want to choose a spelling more closely aligned with the semantics of the resource than a spelling closely aligned with your current storage.